# how can i locate a input element of radio and check it ?always "Unable to find element "

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am learning selenium with c# ,i am trying to get a input element of radio,but always  "Unable to find element "

```
 <div>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch" class="radioListOptions">
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_0" type="radio" checked="checked" value="My" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucObservationSearch1$rblAdvancedSearch">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_0">My</label>
<br>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1" type="radio" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucObservationSearch1$rblAdvancedSearch$1\',\'\')', 0)" value="Workgroup" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucObservationSearch1$rblAdvancedSearch">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1">Workgroup</label>
<br>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_2" type="radio" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucObservationSearch1$rblAdvancedSearch$2\',\'\')', 0)" value="Division" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucObservationSearch1$rblAdvancedSearch">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_2">Division</label>
</span>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
 ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links1 = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[contains(text(),'Workgroup')]"));
 ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links1 = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[contains(@value,'Workgroup')]"));
 IWebElement check =    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1"));
```

and i have also tried in console with javascript

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1").checked=true
```

return "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"
i have no more solution ,i need some help ,thanks

I find there is one more html in this html,maybe that's why always fail,anyone knows how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
          document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1").checked = true;

      });
```

Comment: thanks,not work ,"document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1").checked = true;" didn't return a error ,seems do nothing

Comment: and i have tried " System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);" and " js1.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById(\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucObservationSearch1_rblAdvancedSearch_1\").checked=\"true\"");" it returns error.

Answer (score 0):

driver.SwitchTo().Frame("mainContent");